# Пропадает фокус при бездействии приложения более 15 минут, как отключить?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Есть приложение написанное под  андройд тв. При простое приложения более 15 минут, фокус с выбраного элемента пропадает, если нажать на пульте влево или вправо, то он снова появляется. Screensaver приставки установлен на включение через час, в самом приложении он отключён, что ещё можно посмотреть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решилась добавлением строчки adapter.setHasStableIds(true), при создании фрагмента